# Is it possible to add TailwindCSS into Ionic React?

Tags: ionic-framework, tailwind-css, ionic-react

I am looking into ways of how I can integrate Tailwind CSS into ionic react application, I have tried this but fell into a dead end, I am aware of the the Next.JS and Tailwind CSS starter created by one of the ionic experts but also inspecting that even I fell into a dead end.

Comment: I set it up similar to this. https://codingthesmartway.com/using-tailwind-css-with-react/

Answer (score 3):

Yes we can add TailwindCSS to Ionic React by installing Tailwind CSS with Vite.

**step 1:**
Run this command in terminal

> npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer

**Step 2:**
Run this command in terminal

> npx tailwindcss init -p

**Step 3:**
Configure your template paths,
Add the paths to all of your template files in your tailwind.config.js file.

```css
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

**step 4:**
Add the Tailwind directives to your CSS,

Add the @tailwind directives for each of Tailwind’s layers to your ./src/index.css file.

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

**Step 5:**
Start your build process

Run your build process with :

> ionic serve

**finally**
Start using Tailwind in your project,

Start using Tailwind’s utility classes to style your content.

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold underline">
      Hello world!
    </h1>
  )
}
```

Reference link [Install Tailwind CSS with Vite using React](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite)

Answer (score 1):

[Ionic Framework React](https://ionicframework.com/docs/react) internally uses Create React App (CRA).

Thus following [Tailwindcss CRA setup](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app) work as you would expect.

Just note that you do not need `@tailwind base` since Ionic out of the box already import `normalize.css` for us.

Comment: How is this going to work with 'ionic serve' when that is not in the package.json scripts that are being replaced with craco?

Answer (score 1):

Just as Michael Tran pointed out ionic uses CRA to bootstrap a new react project however, there are some other steps to follow for it to work.

I wrote an article on how this can be achieved you can read my article [here](https://medium.com/@meeky.ae/integrating-tailwindcss-and-ionic-react-application-c038b95af704)

[image]